# Recursive FFT discards the imaginary part

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, fft

I am trying to implement recursive FFT.

```
import numpy as np
from math import e, pi

def rdft(a):
    n = a.size
    if n == 1:
        return a
    i = complex(0, 1)
    w_n = e ** (2 * i * pi / float(n))
    w = 1
    a_0 = np.zeros(int(math.ceil(n / 2.0)))
    a_1 = np.zeros(n / 2)
    for index in range(0, n):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            a_0[index / 2] = a[index]
        else:
            a_1[index / 2] = a[index]
    y_0 = rdft(a_0)
    y_1 = rdft(a_1)
    y = np.zeros(n)
    for k in range(0, n / 2):
        y[k] = y_0[k] + w * y_1[k]
        y[k + n / 2] = y_0[k] - w * y_1[k]
        w = w * w_n
return y



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.array([1, 0,0, -2])
    print rdft(a)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
[-1.  1.  3.  1.]
/path/file.py:22: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part y[k] = complex(y_0[k] + w * y_1[k])
/path/file.py:23: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part y[k + n / 2] = y_0[k] - w * y_1[k]
```

I'm not familiar with complex calculations in Python. The real values are correct but as it says it discards the imaginary part.

Comment: Maybe you want to explain, what your function is supposed to do. When you say polynomial multiplication, you don't mean [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polymul.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polymul), I assume? And please edit your question and post the full traceback.

Comment: You can write the complex part of a number with a `j` suffix, like `2j * pi` as you use it.

Comment: This code does not run. Have you tested yourself what you have pasted?

Comment: Yes, it runs and prints the output. But without the imaginary part.

Comment: The first error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: Yes. it adds the complex() in error code but my code doesn't have it.

Comment: Strange. Not in my error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to cast complex numbers to a numpy array that has been defined as float. To overcome this problem, define `y` as a numpy array with complex values:

```
y = np.zeros(n, dtype = complex)
```

Output after this change:

```
[-1.+0.j  1.+2.j  3.+0.j  1.-2.j]
```

If you want to know more about numpy data types, read the [numpy user guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).